# Excel Pivot table layout for Registrant and payment data

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have data similar to this in an excel pivot table. The pivot table lays it out so that every registration number has 1 row and the person it is associated to it is in the column to the left.

```
Email             Registration  Payment
lalal@gmail.com   546           2
hohoh@gmail.com   547           2
heheh@gmail.com   548           2
                  549           4
                  550           2
jajaj@gmail.com   551           6
```

People can have several registration numbers they use associated under one email. For an email service we are using we need the data to look like this:

```
Email             Registration  Payment  Registration  Payment  Registration  Payment
lalal@gmail.com   546           2
hohoh@gmail.com   547           2
heheh@gmail.com   548           2        549           4        550           2
jajaj@gmail.com   551           6
```

The pivot table should be made so that each email/registrant takes up only 1 row and their registration numbers and payments are side by side in that row. Does anyone know how to do this?